# Play application not picking environment variables from Kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, playframework, google-kubernetes-engine

My YAML file has the following environment variables defined.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codingjediweb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: codingjediweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: codingjediweb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-logs
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: codingjediweb
        image: docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:06072020
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        env:
            - name: db.cassandraUri
              value: cassandra://xx.yy.zzz.ppp:9042
            - name: db.password
              value: 9__
            - name: db.keyspaceName
              value: dbname
            - name: db.username
              value: dbname2
       ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      - name: logging
        image: busybox
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        command: ['sh', '-c', "while true; do sleep 86400; done"]
```

My Play application uses the variables. If a variable is not defined in the config file then Play checks for environment variables.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile

My application picks the configuration as follows:

```scala
 val dbUsernameOption = configuration.getOptional[String]("db.username")

    val dbUsername = dbUsernameOption.map(name => name).getOrElse({
      cassandraRepositoryComponentsLogger.error("unable to pick db username from configuration.")
      ""
    })

    val dbPasswordOption = configuration.getOptional[String]("db.password")
    val dbPassword = dbPasswordOption.map(name=>name).getOrElse({
      cassandraRepositoryComponentsLogger.error("unable to pick db password from configuration.")
      ""
    })
```

When I start the application by applying the Kubernetes YAML file, the container stops and I see an error

```
unable to pick db username from configuration.
unable to pick db password from configuration.
```

I can see that the environment variables are defined in the container.

```sh
# printenv
db.keyspaceName=somename <-- here
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.15.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR=10.15.249.26
HOSTNAME=codingjediweb-649db4fcb9-xxhwm
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT=9000
SHLVL=1
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
HOME=/root
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.15.249.26
db.cassandraUri=cassandra://xxx <-- here
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP=tcp://10.15.249.26:9000
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=9000
CODINGJEDIWEB_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.15.249.26:9000
db.username=something <-- here
TERM=xterm
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.15.240.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.15.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.15.240.1
PWD=/
db.password=9__ <-- here
/ #
```

Am I incorrect that Play will check for environment variables if the configuration is missing in the config file? I am not sure if this is a Play issue or a Kubernetes issue because when I run the Play application in IntelliJ and provide the environment variables in the build configuration then the application works.

[image: IntelliJ]

Comment: Kubernetes' role here is just to create the environment variables as defined in the yaml file. Sine you are able to list them in the container, I think we need to focus on the play side. 

Just to isolate the issue, you may slightly modify the code to read the username and password always from environment variables and test.

Comment: @ManuChadha Hey, If the variables are showing inside the container, than the kubernetes object is well configured, it's the app which is not retrieving it properly. I agree with Rico, mounting Secret as File should fix your issue, if you face issues handling secrets let us know!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that those are JVM environment variables and bash/shell environment variables, hence they are not being picked up.

One option from the K8s perspective is to make your whole config file a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) and the mount it under `conf/application.conf`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: appconf-secret
data:
  application.conf: |
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

Then:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codingjediweb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: codingjediweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: codingjediweb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-logs
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: appconf
        secret:
          secretName: appconf-secret
      containers:
      - name: codingjediweb
        image: docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:06072020
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        - name: appconf
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/conf/application.conf
      ...
```

Another approach is to use your original approach and use [Substitutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Substitutions) in your Play config file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to change to substitutions but that doesn't seem to work either - `cassandraUri=${?DB_CASSANDRA_URI}` where DB_CASSANDRA_URI is an environment variable to be picked from YAML file. I'll check secrets. Didn't know about them :)